# GITHUB OAuth: The code passed is incorrect or expired

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, github, passport.js

I get the code from callback and use it to get access_token, but the res tell me:

> error=bad_verification_code&error_description=The+code+passed+is+incorrect+or+expired.&error_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.github.com%2Fv3%2Foauth%2F%23bad-verification-code

I'm sure I use it first time. I already try it Hundreds of times. I'm going crazy！

Interestingly， it does work at localhost:xxxx but does not work in http://domain.xx.. I can not find why.

Comment: Did you check your GitHub configuration?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure the github configuration is right. I have checked it many times.

Comment: I also met the same problem, the reason is I mixed the confuration of my two registed apps